# Creating a formal letter with variables vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

I want to create an automated report that is printable in vb.net where it will print a formal letter to a list of people in my database and I will send it to them individually but I don't know how to add the names in the list in the report by using a variable

```
Start of letter..... congratulations to *name or variable* ... continuation of letter
```

And should I be using the report form of vb.net or just create a print button where I will code the letter myself?
thanks

Comment: It sounds like an easy problem to help with. However, I can't answer your question because I have no code from you to amend and/or fix.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, this isn't a tutorial site, it is for people with a specific problem with code they have written where they can post relevant code and explain expected behaviour and actual behaviour. Including any errors and show which bit of code produces the error. See [ask] and [mcve]. in your case you should have a look at interpolated strings as @ivanH says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for interpolated string ([$ (Visual Basic Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/special-characters/interpolated))

```
Dim myLetter = $"Start of letter{NameOfVariable1} congratulations to {NameOfVariable2} continuation of letter!"
```